# Arch Linux ARMv6 (RPi B+) boot issue

Tags: archlinux, boot-issues

I am tinkering with different Linux flavours on the B+, but I am having trouble getting the latest ARMv6 Arch distribution up and going.

After following the standard installation steps at http://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv6/raspberry-pi, upon booting, I get the following:

```
sh: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device
sh: no job control in this shell
```

This is then followed by the standard bourne shell prompt. No password prompt, no bash.

I have tried repeating the instructions. Same result.

I'm not accessing remotely using serial or SSH, just directly booting into the machine.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

Current partition scheme:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/mmcblk0

Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 15.7 GB, 15719727104 bytes
4 heads, 16 sectors/track, 479728 cylinders, total 30702592 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xbec0e908

        Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/mmcblk0p1            2048      206847      102400    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk0p2          206848    30702591    15247872   83  Linux
```

Comment: What kind of SD card are you using, what's the partition scheme?

Comment: I assume the card has been working just fine with other distros and is on the OK list (http://elinux.org/RPi_SD_cards)?

Comment: The SD card is a Samsung microSDHC 16GB class 10. It's on the OK list. It worked fine with the old Arch .img files.

Comment: The only things I can find using the catchphrase given above refer to missing binaries. So not necessarily something wrong with the SD card. Do they provide an MD5 hash to check the tarball after download?

Comment: I've checked the MD5 hash, it doesn't seem like there's any problem with the tarball.